# SQL variable not updating in the select query in go client

Tags: mysql, sql, go

I am running the following queries in SQL.

```
SET @thisid=0;
SET @serial=0;

SELECT @serial := IF((@thisid != `places`.`id`), @serial + 1, @serial) as `serial`, @thisid := `places`.`id`, `places`.`id` FROM `places`;
```

The variable @serial basically increments only if the new id is not the same as the last one.
Upon running these queries in the terminal and printing the values of @serial and @thisid, the value received is @thisid='id6' @serial=6.

I executed this query in my go code:

```
if _, err = repo.db.ExecContext(ctx, "SET @thisid=0;"); err != nil {
    return
}

if _, err = repo.db.ExecContext(ctx, "SET @serial=0;"); err != nil {
    return
}

rows, err = repo.db.QueryContext(ctx, fmt.Sprintf(
    "SELECT @serial := IF((@thisid != `places`.`id`), @serial + 1, @serial) as `serial`, @thisid := `places`.`id`, `places`.`id` FROM `places`;",
))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error here")
    return
}

if err = repo.db.QueryRow("SELECT @serial").Scan(&that); err != nil {
    return
}

if err = repo.db.QueryRow("SELECT @thisid").Scan(&this); err != nil {
    return
}
```

Upon printing the values of @thisid and @serial, the value of @thisid is received the same where the value of @serial is received as 0. It doesn't seem to update dynamically.

Comment: Go uses a connection pool, which means each query may happen on a different connection. variables like that are scoped to the connection. If you need them to last between queries, you need to use a transaction to ensure you stay within the same connection.

Comment: @Flimzy Thanks that solves it. If you would answer then I would select yours as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go uses a connection pool, which means each query may happen on a different connection. variables like that are scoped to the connection. If you need them to last between queries, you need to use a transaction to ensure you stay within the same connection.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is really arbitrary.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `select`.  Nor does it guarantee the ordering of the result set.

So, I think you want:

```
select p.*,
       (@rn := if(@id = id, @rn + 1,
                  if(@id := id, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as serial
from (select p.*
      from places p
      order by p.id
     ) p cross join
     (select @id := 0, @rn := 0) params;
```

Comment: The answer I was looking for is the comment. But the fact that not ordering of result of subquery solved my another problem. Thanks